# Does deleting s3 inventory delets the invetory data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to delete an s3 inventory i have setup for an s3 bucket . What i want to know is, deleting s3 inventory deletes the output folder that inventory had created or not?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by "delete an s3 inventory"? Are you referring to the output files provided by [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html)? Therefore, is your question really "If I deactivate Amazon S3 Inventory, will it delete the inventory files it has already created and stored in my bucket"?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, my question is "If I deactivate Amazon S3 Inventory, will it delete the inventory files it has already created and stored in my bucket"?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 Inventory will *not* delete inventory files it has already output.

Comment: P.S. If you ever wonder about such things, you can always test it by creating _another_ bucket, activating S3 inventory, then turning it off.